# Efficient way of finding missing documents in mongo with python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I came across a chunk of code, a function which aims to find missing values in mongo DB, the code looks:

```
def missing(config, list_of_clients):
   collection = connect_2_mongo_db("collection", urls[config], users[config], pwd[config])
   missing_clients = []
   for c in list_of_clients:
      cursor = collection.find({ "ClientID" : c }, {"ClientID" : 1, "_id" : 0 } )
      if len(list(cursor)) == 0:
         missing_clients.append(c)
   return missing_clients
```

Of course this is very expensive in time, is there any better way to get all the missing values at once using a mongo query?
The list_of_clients looks like list_of_clients = [1,2,3] and the documents look like

```
{
   "ClientID": 2,
   "Address" : "blah blah blah"
   ...
}
{
   "ClientID": 3,
   "Address" : "blah blah blah"
   ...
}
```

I want to know which clients are not present in base. In this case 1

Comment: use [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/#nin)

Comment: @Sohaib $nin return documents in mongo. I want documents missing in mongo...

Comment: what do you mean by missing documents? the ones with only `_id`? show us your sample `list_of_clients`.

Comment: @Van Peer I'd updated with more details.

Answer (score 1):

you can query once using the operator [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) and the list of client ids

```
result = coll.find({
    "clientID": { "$in": list_of_clients }
})
```

put the result in a list

```
existing_clients=[]
for c in result:
    existing_clients.append(c["clientID"])
```

and finally get the IDs that are missing from the difference of these lists

```
missing_ids = list(set(list_of_clients)-set(existing_clients))
```

---

same thing, written with list comprehension

```
def missing(list_of_clients):
    e = [c["clientID"] for c in coll.find({"clientID":{"$in":list_of_clients}})]
    return list(set(list_of_clients)-set(e))
```

Comment: This was exactly my first approach, but I was wondering whether we can do it with mongo queries.

Comment: No. You execute `len(list_of_clients)` queries. Here is one query.

Comment: lol, I mean the code I showed is not what I wrote (I found it like that) and my firs approach was to do exactly what you propose, I kwnow this is one query. But I was wondering if this can be achieved only with mongo queries.

Comment: I am not able to imagine your thoughts; I can only read the question,which presents a way to do it, says it is **time expensive** and asks for a more **efficient way** to do it. So here is a probably efficient way, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not having a mongo instance to have tried this out. You can give this a try

```
def missing(config, list_of_clients):
    collection = connect_2_mongo_db("collection", urls[config], users[config], pwd[config])
    missing=[]
    for c in list_of_clients:
        cursor = collection.find({ClientID: {$nin: c}});
        missing.append(cursor)
    return missing
```